# How can I start firefox immediately on boot from the command line using cron?

Tags: command-line, bash, xorg, cron, autostart

I've got a Librecomputer Le Potato, a single-board computer in the style of Raspberry Pi, that I am trying to run Firefox on in kiosk mode. I want it to run Firefox immediately on startup, but since it boots to a command line, I have to start the x server first.

So I have a line in my crontab that looks like:

```
@reboot /home/kiosk/autorun.sh
```

where autorun.sh is just

```
startx /usr/bin/firefox --kiosk -height 1080 -width 1920 ~/display/display.html
```

This works fine if I execute the script manually, but it doesn't (visibly) run at reboot. I've seen some other questions here in which adding

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

to the crontab entry forces the command to output to the X display, but I don't think I can do that here, because the X display doesn't start until the command executes. What should I do instead?

Comment: I am putting this as a comment for now but I think that all you have to do is to put a copy of the `firefox.desktop` file from the `/usr/share/applications/` directory into the `/etc/xdg/autostart/` for it to run at bootup time.

Comment: Whose crontab is *"my crontab"*? That will affect how `~/display/display.html` is expanded. Does your `autorun.sh` have a shebang?